# how to check dependency of mongodb/hibernate plugin in my grails project

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, grails

recently I worked with an grails project using sql as their main database. Now, they want to use sql database and mongodb as the same. Unfortunately, when I add mongodb plugin the project doesn't work anymore.

I tested with simple project, add mongodb plugin and it works.

In my point of view, there are some conflicts between other plugins and mongodb. So, how can I verify these dependency problems?

I am using grails 2.3.7 and trying with mongodb 3.0.1
compile no error, but problem when running. Here is the details:

```
Error Details
Error 500: 
Servlet: gsp
URI: /
Exception Message: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.or(Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Lorg/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/Criteria; 
Caused by: Executing action [index] of controller [com.finensemble.IndexController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action 
Class: IndexController 
At Line: [54] 
Code Snippet:
Stack Trace
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [index] of controller [com.finensemble.IndexController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)

    at com.linkedin.grails.profiler.ProfilerFilter.doFilterInternal(ProfilerFilter.java:82)

    at org.apache.shiro.grails.SavedRequestFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestFilter.java:55)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action

    ... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    ... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.or(Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Lorg/grails/datastore/mapping/query/api/Criteria;

    at com.finansemble.finStore.SaleService$_getActiveSales_closure1.doCall(SaleService.groovy:17)

    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeClosureNode(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1854)

    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1553)

    at com.finansemble.finStore.SaleService.getActiveSales(SaleService.groovy:16)

    at com.finansemble.finStore.SaleService.getActiveSales(SaleService.groovy:11)

    at com.finensemble.IndexController$_closure1.doCall(IndexController.groovy:54)
```

Can I conclude that: hibernate and mongodb depend on some other plugins but in difference version? and the hibernate not load properly?

Comment: Probably you can get help from answer of [**this similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952127/grails-mysql-and-mongodb-together). Seems to be issue of hibernate and mongodb version try downgrade to :hibernate:3.6.10.8

Comment: actually, the issue happen from 2.3.4 in my project (at that time, hibernate is lower version but still generate the same error). Btw the issue you mentioned, is fixed in higher hibernate version (now 2.3.7 grails come with hibernate 3.6.10.10)

Comment: sorry I didn't got what you said. what's your grails, hibernate and mongodb version? Did downgrading helped you or not.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581133/or-in-namedqueries-in-grails-2-3-8-abstractmethoderror

Comment: sorry, I tested with hibernate 3.6.10.8, it still the same. I am using grails 2.3.7; hibernate 3.6.10.10; mongodb 3.0.1;

Comment: Thanks @injecteer, I just simply change back to mongodb 3.0.0; and it works well with: grails 2.3.7; hibernate 3.6.10.10;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `grails dependency-report` and make sure you are using the most recent versions of the `grails-datastore-*` jars.  Normally to achieve this simply upgrade to the latest versions of both `hibernate` and `mongodb`

Comment: actually, I did run `grails dependency-report` but it's too complex and I don't know how to solve the issue!

Comment: @graeme, I added the missing repo and got my hands on `hibernate:3.6.10.14` and it still has dependency conflicts with `mongo:3.0.1`